# Derive the formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares using derivatives and integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, summation

I wanted to prove the formula for sum of squares without using induction and thought using derivatives would be the easiest approach
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)^2\\f'(n)=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)=2\sum_{k=1}^n k=n^2+n\\\int f'(n)dn=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+C$$
Now there is a term $\frac{n}{6}$ which is missing,why is this approach wrong?

Comment: Derivatives don't make sense in this context, as the domain consists of whole numbers (although the polynomial result can be naturally extended), and you are neglecting that the upper limit of summation is also dependent on $n$.  You can take differences, though.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2}&=\lim_{t\ \to\ 0}\partiald[2]{}{t}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\expo{tk}
=\lim_{t\ \to\ 0}\partiald[2]{}{t}
\bracks{\color{#00f}{\expo{\pars{n + 1}t} - 1 \over \expo{t} - 1}}
\end{align}
$\ds{{\tt\mbox{We just need an expansion of the}}\ \color{#00f}{blue}\
\mbox{expression up to}\ t^{2}\ !!!}$.

> Another approach. With $\ds{\verts{z} < 1}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2}&
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k^{2}\sum_{n = k}^{\infty}z^{n}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k^{2}{z^{k} \over 1 - z}
> ={1 \over 1 - z}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k^{2}z^{k}
> ={1 \over 1 - z}\,{z\pars{1 + z} \over \pars{1 - z}^{3}}
> ={z\pars{1 + z} \over \pars{1 - z}^{4}}
> \\[3mm]&=z\pars{1 + z}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\mbox{}-4 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}z^{n}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\mbox{}-4 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}z^{n + 1}
> +\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\mbox{}-4 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}z^{n + 2}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\mbox{}-4 \choose n - 1}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}z^{n}
> +\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{\mbox{}-4 \choose n - 2}\pars{-1}^{n - 2}z^{n}
> \\[3mm]&=1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> {\mbox{}-4 \choose n - 1}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}
> +
> {\mbox{}-4 \choose n - 2}\pars{-1}^{n}}z^{n}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2}&
={\mbox{}-4 \choose n - 1}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}
+{\mbox{}-4 \choose n - 2}\pars{-1}^{n}
\\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{n - 1}{4 + n - 1 - 1 \choose n - 1}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}
+\pars{-1}^{n - 2}{4 + n - 2 - 1 \choose n - 2}\pars{-1}^{n}
\\[3mm]&={n + 2 \choose  n - 1} + {n + 1 \choose n - 2}
={n + 2 \choose  3} + {n + 1 \choose 3}
\\[3mm]&={\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1}n \over 6} + {\pars{n + 1}n\pars{n - 1} \over 6}
={\pars{n + 1}n \over 6}\,\bracks{\pars{n + 2} + \pars{n - 1}}
\\[3mm]&={n\pars{n + 1}\pars{2n + 1} \over 6}
\end{align}